# Help me in writing test class for my triggerclass

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have written a trigger to send email to particular email groups whenever a "Idea" record is created. I have to send emails to groups on the basis of combination of two multi-select picklist fields so I have added those combinations in "Custom Setting Data" and using it to fetch the email id's. Below is my code.

```
Public Class IdeaTriggerOperations1
{
    Public Static Void NotifyBUonNewDiscussion1(List<Idea> IdeaIds)
    { 
        Set<String> CategoryNameSet = new Set<String>();
        Set<String> ProductNameSet = new Set<String>();

        //Set and clear emailAddresses
        String[] emailAddressess = new String[40];
        emailAddressess.clear();

        //Set Messaging
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);

        //Get Email Template Id
        EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developerName = 'Idea_New_Discussion_Posted_BU'];


        For(Idea I : IdeaIds)
        {       
            String completeEmailList = '';                                  
            for(String str : I.Categories.split(';'))
            {
                CategoryNameSet.add(str);
                system.debug('-----------CategoryNameSet--------'+CategoryNameSet);
            } 
            If(I.Product__c != NULL)
            {
                for(String str1 : I.Product__c.split(';'))
                {
                    ProductNameSet.add(str1);
                    system.debug('-----------ProductNameSet--------'+ProductNameSet);
                }
            }
            Else{
                ProductNameSet = NULL; }

            // Generating Email List values for BU ... 
            If(i.Include_BU__c == True)
            { 
                If(!ProductNameSet.contains('Automata') && !ProductNameSet.contains('DRAM') && !ProductNameSet.contains('eMCP') && !ProductNameSet.contains('eMMC') && !ProductNameSet.contains('HMC') && !ProductNameSet.contains('MCP') && !ProductNameSet.contains('NAND') && !ProductNameSet.contains('NOR') && !ProductNameSet.contains('SSD') && !ProductNameSet.contains('N/A'))
                    {
                        Idea_Custom_Setting__c nc = Idea_Custom_Setting__c.getValues('Product All');
                        completeEmailList += nc.BU_Email_Id__c+ ';' ;
                    }

                List<Idea_Custom_Setting__c> IdeaEmails = Idea_Custom_Setting__c.getall().values();
                for(Idea_Custom_Setting__c m : IdeaEmails)
                {
                    If(CategoryNameSet.contains(m.Category__c) && (ProductNameSet.contains(m.Product__c)||ProductNameSet==NULL))
                    {
                        completeEmailList += m.BU_Email_Id__c + ';' ;
                    } 
                    If(CategoryNameSet.contains('Automotive') || CategoryNameSet.contains('Connected Home') || CategoryNameSet.contains('Consumer') || CategoryNameSet.contains('IMM'))
                    If(ProductNameSet.contains(m.Combined_Category__c))
                    {
                        completeEmailList += m.BU_Email_Id__c + ';' ;
                    }               
                }  
            }//End of first IF statement

            // Generating Email List values for SME ...
            If( i.LastModifiedDate == i.CreatedDate)
            {         
                List<Idea_Custom_Setting_For_SME__c> SMECustSet = Idea_Custom_Setting_For_SME__c.getall().values();
                for(Idea_Custom_Setting_For_SME__c  N : SMECustSet)
                {
                    If(CategoryNameSet.contains(N.Category_SME__c)){
                    If(ProductNameSet.contains('N/A'))
                    {
                        completeEmailList += N.SME_Email_Id__c + ';' ;
                    }   }                 
                    If(CategoryNameSet!=NULL && ProductNameSet.contains(N.Product_SME__c))
                    {
                        completeEmailList += N.SME_Email_Id__c + ';' ;
                    }
                    If(!ProductNameSet.contains('Automata') && !ProductNameSet.contains('DRAM') && !ProductNameSet.contains('eMCP') && !ProductNameSet.contains('eMMC') && !ProductNameSet.contains('HMC') && !ProductNameSet.contains('MCP') && !ProductNameSet.contains('NAND') && !ProductNameSet.contains('NOR') && !ProductNameSet.contains('SSD') && !ProductNameSet.contains('N/A')){
                    If(ProductNameSet.contains(N.Special_Value__c))
                    {
                        completeEmailList += N.SME_Email_Id__c + ';' ;
                    }}
                }
            }

           system.debug('-----------completeEmailList--------'+completeEmailList);
           for(String str2 : completeEmailList.split(';'))
           {
               emailAddressess.add(str2);
           }

            //Set Message Properties
            mail.setTargetObjectId(i.CreatedById);
            mail.setWhatId(i.Id);
            mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('SFDC Technical Discussion');
            mail.setToAddresses(emailAddressess);
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setBccSender(false);
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

            // Update the Post to set the SME Notified field to TRUE
           If(i.Include_BU__c == True){
           List<Idea> nIdea = [SELECT Id, BU_Notified__c FROM Idea WHERE Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];

                for (Idea o :nIdea){
                    o.BU_Notified__c = True;
                }

                update nIdea; } 

        }
        // Send the email
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

When I create an Idea record with my test class I always get error saying :

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, IdeaTrigger1: execution
>   of AfterInsert
>
> caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on
>   row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Invalid to address : : []
>
> Class.IdeaTriggerOperations1.NotifyBUonNewDiscussion1: line 114,
>   column 1 Trigger.IdeaTrigger1: line 9, column 1: []

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you are creating your email address list with 40 empty records then adding more so:

change

```
String[] emailAddressess = new String[40];
```

to

```
String[] emailAddressess = new String[]{};
```

As long as you have proper email addresses elsewhere and the rest of your code works this will fix the issue in your question.....